# gettin invalid registration i used the phonegap-plugin-push "success":0,"failure":1,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"error":"InvalidRegistration"}]}

Tags: cordova, push-notification, push

gettin invalid registration i used the phonegap-plugin-push "success":0,"failure":1,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"error":"InvalidRegistration"}]}

I am trying the https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push phonegap latest plugin below is my java script code and php code

and using ionic cordova

PHP CODE

```
enter code here

<?php
// API access key from Google API's Console
define( 'API_ACCESS_KEY', 'AIzaSyBEzOLapgBPKJ-c_NU8rVsoU6k2e_Q-YqA' );


echo $_GET['id'];
$registrationIds = array( $_GET['id'] );//


// prep the bundle
$msg = array
(
'message'   => 'here is a message. message',
   'title'      => 'This is a title. title',
'subtitle'  => 'This is a subtitle. subtitle',
'tickerText'    => 'Ticker text here...Ticker text here...Ticker text here',
'vibrate'   => 1,
'sound'     => 1,
'largeIcon' => 'large_icon',
'smallIcon' => 'small_icon'
);
$fields = array
(
'registration_ids'  => array($registrationIds),
'data'          => $msg
);

$headers = array
(
'Authorization: key=' . API_ACCESS_KEY,
'Content-Type: application/json'
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_URL, 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send' );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POST, true );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields ) );
$result = curl_exec($ch );
curl_close( $ch );
echo $result;
```

javascript code to get and send registration id here

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

// Wait for device API libraries to load
//
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

// device APIs are available
//
function onDeviceReady() {
 var push = PushNotification.init({ "android": {"senderID": "280872888677"},
     "ios": {}, "windows": {} } );

 push.on('registration', function(data) {
    var url = 'http://mywebsite.com/reest/pushn.php?               id='+data.registrationId;
   alert(url);
   //post url
  $.post( url, function( data ) {
  alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );
```

});
    });

```
push.on('notification', function(data) {
    // data.message,
    // data.title,
    // data.count,
    // data.sound,
    // data.image, 
    // data.additionalData
});

push.on('error', function(e) {
    alert(e.message);
});


}
</script>
```

Comment: Please make sure you are using correct gcm id here `{"senderID": "280872888677"}`?

Comment: same issue for me. i am using phonegap-plugin-push plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I tried to use this library, but I faced the same problem, then I decided to change this library and use **PushPlugin**, it is very easy to use and straightforward. Here is the link of it : https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin

Comment: I am not able to build the project when i do the automatic install it gives me some error code 8 and now i have done the manual install.Can you tell me how did you generate the device registrationid?

Comment: I am not able to buid the project when i add this plugin

Comment: Is there any other solution to this problem??

Comment: yes bro, I faced exactly the same problem. the solution is only to download the previous version which is PushPlugin 2.4.0 and here is the link of it https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin/releases/tag/2.4.0. just send me if it is solved your problem bro. Cheers

Comment: Hi bro @Nadeem Khoury Can you tell me the procedure to add old version plugin using the command line?

Comment: I have now installed the older version of the plugin using commandline  cordova plugin add https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin#2.4.0 it has got installed ( version 2.4.0)and now app is also getting build however I am still getting invalid registration.Is there any other way I can try to try to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by editing my php code to this below code

```
//------------------------------
// Payload data you want to send 
// to Android device (will be
// accessible via intent extras)
//------------------------------

$data = array( 'message' => 'Hello World!' );

//------------------------------
// The recipient registration IDs
// that will receive the push
// (Should be stored in your DB)
// 
// Read about it here:
// http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/
//------------------------------

$ids = array( $_GET['id'] );//array( 'abc', 'def' );

//------------------------------
// Call our custom GCM function
//------------------------------

sendGoogleCloudMessage(  $data, $ids );

//------------------------------
// Define custom GCM function
//------------------------------

function sendGoogleCloudMessage( $data, $ids )
{
//------------------------------
// Replace with real GCM API 
// key from Google APIs Console
// 
// https://code.google.com/apis/console/
//------------------------------

$apiKey = 'apikey';

//------------------------------
// Define URL to GCM endpoint
//------------------------------

$url = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';

//------------------------------
// Set GCM post variables
// (Device IDs and push payload)
//------------------------------

$post = array(
                'registration_ids'  => $ids,
                'data'              => $data,
                );

//------------------------------
// Set CURL request headers
// (Authentication and type)
//------------------------------

$headers = array( 
                    'Authorization: key=' . $apiKey,
                    'Content-Type: application/json'
                );

//------------------------------
// Initialize curl handle
//------------------------------

$ch = curl_init();

//------------------------------
// Set URL to GCM endpoint
//------------------------------

curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );

//------------------------------
// Set request method to POST
//------------------------------

curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );

//------------------------------
// Set our custom headers
//------------------------------

curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );

//------------------------------
// Get the response back as 
// string instead of printing it
//------------------------------

curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );

//------------------------------
// Set post data as JSON
//------------------------------

curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $post ) );

//------------------------------
// Actually send the push!
//------------------------------

$result = curl_exec( $ch );

//------------------------------
// Error? Display it!
//------------------------------

if ( curl_errno( $ch ) )
{
    echo 'GCM error: ' . curl_error( $ch );
}

//------------------------------
// Close curl handle
//------------------------------

curl_close( $ch );

//------------------------------
// Debug GCM response
//------------------------------

echo $result;
}
```